# iOS Accessibility - control which UI object gets the focus

Tags: ios, uiaccessibility

I'm having trouble identifying why a UIButton ( specifically a UIBarButtonItem, the menu button in my case) gets the accessibility focus when a UIViewController changes.

The problem is it "cuts" the announcement being read and takes the focus at no need.

So my questions:

1. How do I find "who" is giving a UI object an accessibility focus. (I tried to override the becomeFirstResponder - it never gets called).
2. How do I select, programmatically, which UI object gets the accessibility focus now.

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

To select which object becomes first responder, you can simply call

`[becomeFirstResponder()][1]`

on the UIResponder object you want to be the focus.

Comment: problem is "my" becomeFirstResponder" gets hijacked by another ui component ( which i tried to override its "becomeFirstResponder" function to see who called it, but the breakpoint never worked )